# Vb.net mouse double click event for button

Tags: vb.net

I just started to learning vb.net Windows form Application. I found that in button mouse double click event isn't firing. When i searched, i found that double click event for button will not fire. If it's true then why it's given ? It's shown in microsoft's documentation also. So i think it should work.  in  I tried by setting the  setstyle.  :

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, True)
```

Can anybody will tell what to do? And reason for that.
Any help will be appreciated.
TIA

Comment: What `Button` is this? `WinForm`?

Comment: Yes in windows form application

Comment: Button derives from Control. Control has DoubleClick And this is the documentation on MSDN about [Control.DoubleClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: see also: [mousedoubleclick doesnt work for dynamically created button](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23716554/1070452)